# Rollover Image jQuery help

Tags: jquery

I basically want to have a small thumbnail of an image, and when the user puts the mouse over the image I want a larger version to pop-up. I've been doing some Google and I found this [tutorial](http://www.frodesigns.com/2009/07/wordpress-jquery-image-rollovers/).

I cant make sense of the code. Which file should I put it in?

```
jQuery(function($) {                    <--This is the enclosing function
$(document).ready(function(){       <--This is the overall jQuery function

    $("#content #quote img").each(function () {    <--This function determines img src
        rollsrc = $(this).attr("src");
        rollON = rollsrc.replace(/.png$/gi, "-hover.png");
        $("<img>").attr("src", rollON);
    });

    $("#content #quote a").mouseover(function () {  <--This displays the -hover image
        imgsrc = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
        matches = imgsrc.match(/-hover/);
        if (!matches) {
            imgsrcON = imgsrc.replace(/.png$/gi, "-hover.png");
            $(this).children("img").attr("src", imgsrcON);
        }
    });

    $("#content #quote a").mouseout(function () {  <--This returns the image to normal
        $(this).children("img").attr("src", imgsrc);
    });

});
});
```

Is there a plugin that already does this, or is there an easier way to do this? Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you should put that in the `functions.js` file (create it if it does not exist), and make sure it is embedded in your wordpress site with [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in your `functions.php` file in your theme.